# Given the following condition, which of the following are true and why?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

$\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ are $n \times n$ matrices.

Given above, which of the following are true and why?

A.) If $\mathbf{A}$ is diagonalizable, then $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible.

B.) If there exists a basis for $R^n$ consisting entirely of eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$, then $\mathbf{A}$ is diagonalizable.

C.) $\mathbf{A}$ is diagonalizable if $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{PDP}^{-1}$ for some diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D}$ and some invertible matrix $\mathbf{P}$.

D.) $\mathbf{A}$ is diagonalizable if and only if $\mathbf{A}$ has $n$ eigenvalues, counting multiplicities.

Only B is true. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: what does diagonalizable mean?  $A$ being the zero matrix is interesting for some of these.